# Get songs titles from ipods

Tags: synchronization, ipod

I'm trying to create a PC (Windows) program to sync the song list (just the titles, not the music files themselves) from an iPod with a remote server. 
I want to know if it is possible at all. How can I access the iPod music list?
Or is there a way for doing this using iTunes? Maybe there is a file where iTunes stores the iPod music list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MobileDevice library](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library) natively on Windows if you manage to find a reverse engineered header file for it. You may also try to port [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) from Linux to Windows using MinGW or alike.